# Changing UCI output to include piece names

Tags: software, programming, uci

UCI output from engines is generally raw in the form of g1f3 and e2e4 representing Nf3 and Pe4. One engine I saw (lozza) sends its PV output with the piece names.  Others, like Stockfish, don't include the piece names in their PV.

How do I get the piece names to show in the PV? I am working on creating my first user GUI, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: There is probably some open source code out there somewhere. I just don't know where it is yet.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/oganm/stockfisher/blob/master/R/longToShort.R)'s an R example. Not quite sure if it's perfect yet. If you got to write your own, I'd be interested in seeing it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are expected to have your own internal chess board. If you don’t have one, you could parse the FEN you give to the engine and work out the pieces.

Answer (score 1):

With the EGN (from, to) you can simply do a check up on what piece exist on the `from` position.

Say the engine gives you `a2a4` you then simply check what exists on `a2` and then generate information based on that.

You can do this cause your GUI will always have the same chess board as the engine. It's the engine that recieves a FEN string from the GUI anyways.